# Cannot pass parameter with h:commandLink inside p:dialog and p:panel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, parameter-passing

My configuration: JSF 2.2 - mojara version 2.2.8 Glassfish server 4.0 Primefaces 5.1.7

I have a problem when I try to pass f:param with h:commandLink inside p:dialog inside p:panel. Here is the code for h:commandLink

```
<h:commandLink action="#{creditApplicationAttachmentBean.uploadFile()}" styleClass="mystyle-btn" id="uploadFileButton"><i/> #{msg['mymessage.upload.button']} 
            <f:ajax execute="ids of elemets to execute" render="ids of elements to update"/>
            <f:param name="showMessageInGlobal" value="false"/>
        </h:commandLink>
```

So when action is fired the param is never set(it is null). I have checked for nested forms and do not have them. No validation errors. So all seems to be good a part from parameter is not set.

Please any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and asking people around the answer is simple there is a feature with jsf 2.2 of majara implementation f:param does not work with f:ajax. It also allows special parameters defined but nothing else. there has been request made to include it in jsf 2.3 version. So we will wait and see.

Comment: Huh? This should just work. You only used `execute="ids of elemets to execute"` which is obviously completely wrong.

Comment: @BalusC I just put there explanation of what i have in this attribute and that i'm using them as well. it is not actual ids of my elements :)

Answer (score 0):

f:param must work with command link but try to use   also and for test remove ajax, and the first try to pass parameter. Also check param handle code from JSF bean, if you use f:param, you should get it from parameters map,
here is a link for help 
[PropertyActionListener](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-setpropertyactionlistener-example/)